# I am trying to integrate Google Sign into my python, flask web application and i got the following error

Tags: python, flask, google-signin

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Amabel/PycharmProjects/SystemSecurity/AlienFurniture/main.py", line 1178, in 
app.run(debug=True)
AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'run'

```
app = flask.Blueprint('google_auth', __name__)
```

Am I doing the right method? How do i integrate Google Sign in option into python flask web application with mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not right.

> **BLUEPRINT FILE, normally called views.py**

```
from flask import blueprint, render_template

google_auth = Blueprint('google_auth', __name__)

@google_auth.route('/auth', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def auth():
    #do staff
    return render_template('auth.html')
```

> **APPLICATION FILE app.py**

```
form flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#do stuff


#import the blueprint
#Important note, import the blueprint after the Database functions

from myapp.auth.views import google_auth
app.register_blueprint(google_auth)
```